# Error en funcion asyncrona con await

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

Buenas tengo un backend en nodejs express mongoose. En el controlador de usuarios tengo una función asíncrona para sacar si ese usuario me esta siguiendo o le estoy siguiendo.

La cuestión es que la funcion asyncrona. Primero comprueba los usuarios que sigue y luego los que le siguien. 
Pues bien cuando hago la consulta por get en otro método que hace una llamada a esta funcion asyncrona siempre me devuelve el resultado como undefined. Pero he hecho varios console logs y veo que el primer console log dentro del find como por ejemplo console.log('follows_clean') si me esta sacando bien los resultados tal como quiero. 
En cambio despues del return compruebo si el resultado se le ha asignado a la variable por ejemplo de following y esta como undefinid. No se esta asignando los resultados del find a la variable.

os dejo el código haber si alguien me puede ayudar.

```js
async function followUserIds(user_id){
  var following = await Follow.find({"user": user_id}).select({'_id':0, '_v':0, 'user':0}).exec((err, follow) =>{
    var follows_clean = [];

    follow.forEach((follow) => {
      follows_clean.push(follow.followed)
    });

    console.log(follows_clean);
    return follows_clean;
  });
  console.log(following);

  var followed = await Follow.find({"followed": user_id}).select({'_id':0, '_v':0, 'followed':0}).exec((err, follow) =>{
    var follows_clean = [];

    follow.forEach((follow) => {
      follows_clean.push(follow.user)
    });
    console.log(follows_clean);
    return follows_clean;
  });
  console.log(followed);

    
  return {
    following: following,
    followed: followed
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he solucionado la funcion asyncrona haciendo un catch para así asegurar los resultados de las consultas.

```js
async function followThisUsers(identity_user_id, user_id) {
    var following = await Follow.findOne({ "user": identity_user_id, "followed": user_id }).exec().then((follow) => {
        return follow;
    }).catch((err) => {
        return handleError(err);
    });
 
    var followed = await Follow.findOne({ "user": user_id, "followed": identity_user_id }).exec().then((follow) => {
        console.log(follow);
        return follow;
    }).catch((err) => {
        return handleError(err);
    });
 
 
    return {
        following: following,
        followed: followed
    }
}
```